# ASP.NETにてPDF文書をマウスを動かしなが文字を取得する方法が知りたいです。

Tags: asp.net

OS VisualStudio2019
Net-Framework 4.7.2

以前作成したモジュールが行方不明になりもう一度一から作り直そうと思うのですが
ヒントになるNet情報が見当たりません。
ヒントになるNet情報を教えて頂けたらと思います｡

Comment: この辺の記事 [PDFの文字がコピーできない！Chrome拡張機能「PDF Viewer」でテキストコピー](https://lonely-logs.com/pdf_viewer_chrome_extension), [Firefox で PDF ファイルを表示するか他のビューアーを選択する](https://support.mozilla.org/ja/kb/view-pdf-files-firefox-or-choose-another-viewer) でのブラウザ側の設定とか、その上で表示されたページ上でのブラウザのマウスイベント等が処理出来るようであれば、何とかなるかもしれませんね。ただ、画像データになっているPDFは駄目でしょうが。いずれにしても @sayuri さん回答のように、ASP.NET にてというのとはちょっと違う感じがします。

Answer (score 1):

PDFという時点でどうにもなりません。WebブラウザーはPDFクライアントに制御を渡すため、ASP.NETの管理外となります。
どうしても制御したいのであれば、PDFをHTMLに変換した上で処理することになるでしょうか。

Comment: sayuriさんのHTMLに変換した上で処理する方法を探ってみます｡

Comment: @user47828 質問時とログインIDが異なっているためコメントが出来ない状態のようです (今回はこちらで変換しておきました)。ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。参考: [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)